# Firebase Ordering for a LatLng Fence

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase db like this:

/posts/userid/latitude = -23...
/posts/userid/longitude = -46...

I need to do a Query in Firebase to return only the posts between a LatLng Bound I have.
I have tried orderByChild, orderbyValue.

What is the best way to do that in Android?

Comment: See https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment Frank left, it looks like you can do something like this:

```
        Query firebaseQuery = databaseReference.orderByChild("g").startAt(query.getStartValue()).endAt(query.getEndValue());
```

Taken from here:

https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/firebase/geofire/GeoQuery.java

Comment: Thanks  a lot. I am newbie in Firebase and now things are more clear.